# Python 2.6 unittest - how to set a value to use for a global variable in a function that you're testing

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm having trouble setting the value of a global variable in a function that I'm writing for unit tests.

The function is probably not ready to be used in a test. Or at least to be used to test in an easy manner, but I'm trying to work around that.

Here is an example of the function I'm trying to test:

```
def my_func_with_globals(filepath):
  spos=filepath.find(__my_global_var1)
  new_path = filepath[0:spos] + __my_global_var2
  return new_path

def some_function():
  ...
  my_func_with_globals(filepath)
  ...

if __name__ = '__main__':
  global __my_global_var1
  __my_global_var1='value1'  
  global __my_global_var2
  __my_global_var2='value2'
  ...
  some_function()
```

And here is an example of my test:

```
import unittest
from my_module import *

class UnitTestMyModule(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_my_func_with_globals(self):
    self.assertEqual(my_func_with_globals('arbitrary/file/path'), 'valid output')
```

Another example of my test using @kdopen's suggestion (gives me the same error):

```
import unittest
import my_module

class UnitTestMyModule(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_my_func_with_globals(self):
      my_module.__my_global_var1='some/value'
      my_module.__my_global_var2='second_val'
      self.assertEqual(my_module.my_func_with_globals('arbitrary/file/path'), 'valid output')
```

I keep getting the error:

> NameError: global name '__my_global_var1' is not defined.

I've tried a few different things, but I can't get anything to work. Using unittest.mock.patch looks like it would work perfectly, but I'm stuck with what I currently have with v2.6.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The globals are defined with a double leading underscore, so they are not imported by the `from my_module import *` statement.

You *can* make them accessible with the following:

```
from my_module import __my_global_var1, __my_global_var2
```

Alternatively, if you used `import my_module` you can access them as `my_module.__my_global_var1` etc.

But I don't see any reference to the global variables in your sample test case

Here's a simple example

a.py

```
__global1 = 1

def foo():
    return __global1
```

b.py:

```
import a

print "global1: %d" % a.__global1
print "foo: %d" % a.foo()
a.__global1 = 2
print "foo: %d" % a.foo()
```

And running `b.py`

```
$ python2.6 b.py 
global1: 1
foo: 1
foo: 2
```

UPDATE:

Dang it, missed the obvious

You declare the variables within the `if` test. That code doesn't run on `import` - only when you execute `python my_module` from the command line.

During importing, `__name__` will be set to `my_module`, not `__main__`

So, yes - they **are** undefined when you call your unit test.

Comment: I've actually tried doing 'import my_module' and then setting the values to use in my test with my_module.__my_global_var1 and my_module.__my_global_var2, and I still get the same error 'NameError: global name '__my_global_var1' is not definted'

Comment: then it seems there's something else going on ... are the globals actually defined in `my_module` or does it import something else (or perhaps they're in the `__init__.py`)

Comment: have added working code, explicitly run using python v2.6 ... though it **is** v2.6.9

Comment: And I've just added the real problem with your code ;)

Comment: lol, good catch! I completely didn't realize that `__name__` would be set to `my_module`, not `__main__` on import. I set the global vars in the if test as `my_module.__my_global_var1`and the world is right again. Great explanation btw!